# ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall storage section , "autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition"

Tags: system-installation, automation, pxe

I try to customize storage layout in user-data for autoinstall
here is part of my user-data

```
  storage:
    #layout:
    #  name: direct
    config:
      - type: disk
        match:
          size: largest
          #ssd: true
        id: ssd0
        ptable: gpt
        wipe: superblock
      - type: partition # create partitions on ssd0
        number: 1
        id: efi-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: 256M
        flag: boot        # uefi partition needs boot flag
        grub_device: true # and must be the grub device?
      - type: partition
        number: 2
        id: boot-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: 768M
      - type: partition
        number: 3
        id: root-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: -1
      - type: format # format partitions on ssd0
        id: efi-format
        volume: efi-partition
        fstype: fat32 # ESP gets FAT32
        label: ESP
      - type: format
        id: boot-format
        volume: boot-partition
        fstype: ext4
        label: BOOT
      - type: format
        id: root-format
        volume: root-partition
        fstype: ext4 # / (root) gets ext4, xfs, btrfs
        label: ROOT
      - type: mount # mount formatted partitions on ssd0
        id: root-mount # / (root) gets mounted first
        device: root-format
        path: /
      - type: mount
        id: boot-mount # /boot gets mounted next
        device: boot-format
        path: /boot
      - type: mount
        id: efi-mount # /boot/efi gets mounted next
        device: efi-format
        path: /boot/efi
```

then I got this error during the installation

"autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition"

I am really frustrated with this "autoinstller" ...

Comment: I second the frustration of the autoinstaller.

Answer (score 2):

As I ran in the same issue mentioned here (among others), I followed @dleidert suggestion to run interactive and look at the resulting config.

For me the fix was to add `grub_device: true` to the `disk`, not a partition. The `wipe: superblock` and `preserve: false` was also added to literally everything in the generated config.
Actually quite similar to the example in the docs: https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html#basic-layout

Also, the `grub_boot` partition seems to be needed, without it `grub-install` will fail. Below the two relevant parts:

**Update**: it's more complicated than that, but logical :D

MBR/BIOS: the `grub_device: true` must be on `disk` level.

```
    config:
      - type: disk
        id: disk-vda
        ptable: gpt
        path: /dev/vda
        wipe: superblock-recursive
        preserve: false
        grub_device: true
```

bios_grub partition:

```
      - type: partition
        id: grub-partition
        device: disk-vda
        size: 1M
        flag: bios_grub
        partition_type: EF02
        wipe: superblock
        preserve: false
```

GPT/UEFI: the `grub_device: true` must be on the `efi` partition. A `bios_grub` partition is not needed. But you should add `reorder_uefi: false`.

```
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: false
    config:
      - type: disk
        id: disk-vda
        ptable: gpt
        path: /dev/vda
        wipe: superblock-recursive
        preserve: false
```

efi partition:

```
      - type: partition
        id: boot-partition
        device: disk0
        size: 512M
        flag: boot
        partition_type: EF00
        wipe: superblock
        preserve: false
        grub_device: true
```

Comment: This helped to some extend. However, after this, got an error at stage 'Installing grub at target devices'

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `grub_device: false` for the disk itself. Also, is `fstype: fat32` actually allowed? I think this should be `vfat`.

However, you can make `storage` an interactive section (this will void your storage section), run the installer with your system set to UEFI (JFTR: enabling secure boot is fine), and compare the resulting user-data file you'll find in `/var/log/installer/` with yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `largest` as a partition size.  It is only used in a `match` block.

From your `user-data`.

```
      - type: partition
        number: 3
        id: root-partition
        device: ssd0
        size: largest
```

Comment: yup , I find that error too , but after fix that part , there's another error "autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition"

Comment: @EricChang did you try to add `grub : install_device : - ssd0-boot` section?

Comment: yes , I did, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

after couple days of testing , maybe it's related to  UEFI/BIOS booting , with the acer desktop , when I boot the desktop in BIOS mode (secure boot disable, CSM enabled with legacy mode ) with default storage layout

```
storage:
  layout:
    name: direct
```

the auto install goes without error , but after installation complete , the machine just won't boot into ubuntu.
then I boot with live USB to check the disk layout , there's a 1MB partition with type bios_grub , I don't know if this looks correct.

and then I try to boot the machine with UEFI mode (secure boot disable / CSM disable ) , the machine won't boot into installer , I have to create configure PXE with UEFI ( this is another story) , this time , with the same user-data, the installer create a 1G partition with type ESP and after reboot, damn , the machine boots and go into ubuntu desktop !!!

I don't know if all these testings means something , but is the ubuntu 22.04 did not welcome BIOS booting ? Shall I consider to not use BIOS booting anymore ?